# ReactJS - can not get information about input

Tags: reactjs, components, refs

i´m new with reactjs. I don´t know how can i get the value of my input fields. The best way i show you how i code the component:

```
create class inputFields extends React.Component{ 
  getAllInformationAsJSON() {
    return {
        company : this.refs.company.getText(),
        street : this.refs.street.getText(),
        plz : this.refs.plz.getText(),
        city : this.refs.city.getText(),
        description : this.refs.description.getText(),

    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div style={cssStyle.bodyStyle}>
            <FormComponentText ref="company"   placeholder= {Translation.Location.firmaPlaceholder}/>
            <FormComponentText ref="street" placeholder={Translation.Location.streetPlaceholder}/>
            <FormComponentText ref="plz" width='20%' placeholder={Translation.Location.PLZPlaceholder}/>
            <FormComponentText ref="city" width='80%' placeholder={Translation.Location.placePlaceholder}/>
            <FormComponentArea ref="description" rows='7' placeholder={Translation.Location.descriptionPlaceholder}/>
            <div><button onClick={this.getAllInformationAsJSON}>Test</button></div>
        </div >
    )
}
}
```

if i render this in the html document it works fine!

```
render(){
      return (<inputFields />)
}
```

then i get all information if i call the function. But i want to put this component in an other component:

```
addChild(component) {

    viewTitle = Translation.Settings.User.title;
    viewConfig.view.window.width = 600;
    viewConfig.view.window.height = 400;
    *bodyInfo* = <**inputFields**  />;

    this.props.addComponentToView(<JSPanel idInfo="" config={viewConfig} title={viewTitle} bodyInfo={*bodyInfo*}/>);
}
```

an the JSPanel:

```
class JSPanel extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.sendInformation = this.sendInformation.bind(this);
}


sendInformation() {
    var test = findDOMNode("TEST");
    request("/componente/location", requestData.POST, '{info:test}', requestData.CONTENT_JSON)
        .then(token => {

        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}


render() {
    return this.state.showImage ? (<div ref="ich" style={this.state.css.view}>
            <div style={this.state.css.body}>
                {this.props.**bodyInfo**}
            </div>
        </div>
    ) : (<div></div>)
}
```

What i want is to get the information from the input by the function: sendInformation()

i hope this was clear what i mean and anyone can help me?

best regards

Comment: Who's tutorial have you followed to achieve this results? I suggest you take a deep look on facebook react docs

Comment: Is this the wrong way? I didn`t follow some tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of doing this is to store the values in the state  as the user types them https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: ok, but how can i get the state information from the component in the sendInformation() function? That is my biggest problem.